# Getting TypeError using get_queryset() in my Class Based Generic Views

Tags: django, generics, view

The error says :

get() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

I am sub classing DetailView as :

```
class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'examples/generic_movie_detail.html'
    template_object_name = 'movie'

    def get_queryset(self):
        movie = get_object_or_404(Movies, actors__name__contains = self.args[0])
        return movie
```

and using url as :

```
(r'^movie/detail/(\w+)', MovieDetail.as_view())
```

Now i want to retrieve movies by any particular actor say ('Tom') then i will pass Tom through url as "/movie/detail/tom " . I will work it out in my template then .

Traceback :

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  47.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  68.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Exception Type: TypeError at /examples/movie/detail/aamir
Exception Value: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `BaseDetailView.get` arguments via your URL capturing group (the `(\w+)`) when it doesn't accept arguments.

```
class BaseDetailView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs): #<-- only keyword args
```

Either pass it keyword arguments or override the `get` method to accept `*args` or your specific argument.

Comment: Hey Yuji Thanks . I am new using Django Generic Views . Can you please elaborate on what exactly should be done ?

Comment: You'd need to override the `get` method to accept args - say `def get(self, request, w_arg): return http.HttpResponse(w_arg)` (it works exactly like a normal view function).

Answer (score 0):

If you are subclassing `DetailView`, try overriding `get_object` and not `get_queryset`.

**Edit:** Yuji Tomita's answer below seems the right answer for your question, you should probably use probably use `self.kwargs['name']` and `(r'^movie/detail/(?P<name>\'+)/$', MovieDetail.as_view())`

Keep in mind that for a detail view you probably would want to receive exactly one result for a url, and you should use an unique identity field and an "exact" filter instead of a using a foreign key lookup and use "contains".

Comment: Can you add the full backtrace to your question?

Comment: Is your model name `Movie` or `Movies`?

Comment: Still trying to figure out the problem

Comment: I understand i should use exact filter since DetailView is use for a single object .